# coldfusion 10 cfinclude gives site cannot be reached error

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a action page that redirects to a page based on condition.

I thought of Including that page insted of redirection.

So i used cfinclude function to include this file.

But including that file doesn't work.

But when i open that page in browser it is working fine without error.

For Ex.

http://domain.com/page2.cfm?cutomerID=10
is working fine.

IN http://domain.com/page1.cfm

I am including below code.

`<cfset url.customerID = 10>
<cfinclude template="page2.cfm">`

Even i tried to add only HTML content which i get in page source for "http://domain.com/page2.cfm?cutomerID=10"

It is still not working including a coldfusion page with just html text without any coldfusion code.

Strange thing is When i tried to remove some text from this html content it works for some time but when i reload it stops and give the below error again.

I am not sure if cfinclude has to do anything  page length or some other factors.

Screenshot for error is attached below.

[Error Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09tTQ.png)

Comment: post the error along with your code here(update your question)

Comment: update your cfinclude code in question. showing your syntax may help others to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep . This is my first day in this site. I am new to this.

Comment: welcome. try including from base folder 
<cfinclude template="/base_folder_name/folder/page2.cfm" />

Comment: i think you can't set a URL parameter. you can check it or use it but can't change it. why you wan't to change your url parameter? url.customerid..?

Comment: Insted of redirction to   http://domain.com/page2.cfm?customerID=10 

I am setting up the url.customerID and inluding page2.cfm where i need url.customerID parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a link you can have it as:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset href="domain.com/page2.cfm?customerID=#customerid#&etc=#etc#" />
</cfoutput>
```

For your question you can use this:

```
<cfset custID = 10/>
<cfinclude template="page2.cfm">
In page2.cfm:
<cfif isDefined(url.customerID) || isDefined(custID)>
    <!--- your etc code here --->
</cfif>
```

Note: If you don't want to use url.customerID you can simply delete the occurance

Comment: *You can't set a value for URL for your current page*  Sure you can modify url parameters. `url` is just a structure that can be modified like any other.

Comment: Same issue even i use your Code.

The code which i have used , i have used at other place also . There it is working fine.

But for specific page i am not able to findout issue.

Comment: are the paths of the two files which give correct result and wrong result were same..?